# How to remove Windows 8.1 Components (The way NTLite software does)

Tags: windows-8.1

How can i customize the operating system i'm currently using? I want to remove some components like "Accessibility Tools" , "HomeGroup", "TelnetServer" , "Windows Firewall" and etc.. I also want to remove some pre-installed drivers and services.

From windows control panel it's easy to uninstall some features but not the components i want.

Software called "NTLite" can do this but it's shareware. Is there any freeware alternative to this software?

I can do these with some (dirty)registry edits and manual deletion of files but i'm pretty sure that there is a high possiblity to damage os.

Is there any clean(safe) way to do these?

Comment: there is no safe way. NTLite simply deletes th files and matching registry keys like all older tools (nLte, vLite) do it. This only causes issues. With the "features on demand" you can remove some compomments and Windows will reinstall them later if needed. But wit NTLIte they are gone for ever.

Answer (score 1):

Some Windows 8.1 components, folders and shortcuts are vital for updates to succeed (e.g. folder C:UsersDefaultAppDataLocalMicrosoftWindowsWinX; see http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-8-1-update-fails-to-install). To my own regret, I found that by "cleaning up" some of the shortcuts in the*Programs* [All Users] folder, Windows update failed. So rather than try to remove those items, you might be better off hiding them (such as changing a file attribute to hidden) and/or disabling Windows Services associated with some. They take up little room and consume virtually no CPU time.